# Android handler java to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, libgdx

I am trying the control of admob in libgdx. I found some java codes but I could not translate java to kotlin.  Can you help me. Thanks.

```
private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
    private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;
    protected AdView adView;


    Handler handler = new Handler(){


        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what){
                case SHOW_ADS:
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case HIDE_ADS:
                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Android studio converted like this

```
 var handler: Handler = object : Handler() {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            when (msg.what) {
                SHOW_ADS -> adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                HIDE_ADS -> adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            }
        }
    }
```

the error:This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur (anonymous android.os.Handler)

Comment: _"I am always getting error"_ You need to say exactly what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation is overly complicated in the first place. Just use a standard Handler without subclassing it and modifying how it handles messages. You can post a Runnable to it instead. Then you don't have to worry about message codes either.

```
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

override fun showAds(show: Boolean) = handler.post { 
    adView.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By overriding `Handler`'s `public void handleMessage(Message msg)` you have created an `anonymous` class. In short there is a good possibility that the handler could exist longer than the enclosing class. Which is a no no because an inner class is referenced by the outer class. Easiest fix is to make a separate `class` that `extends` `Handler` and `override handleMessage(Message msg)` there instead of inside of the other class.

EDIT when it comes to any Android OS specific classes `Fragments/Activities...` `anonymous` classes don't work, for same reason why you don't pass `args` into constructors of `fragments`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution.

```
private val handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            when(msg.what){
               SHOW_ADS->{adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)} 
                HIDE_ADS->{adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)}


        }
```